# Split shortcodes to array of shortcodes

Tags: php, shortcode

For example, I have a very complex shortcodes like this:

```
[shortcode-1 attr1 attr2]
    [child-shortcode-1 attr1="231czx"]
        ...
    [/child-shortcode-1]
    [child-shortcode-2 /]
[/shortcode-1]
[shortcode-2 attr1="cxzc"]
    ...
[/shortcode-2]
[shortcode-3 attr1="123" attr2="456" /]
```

How can I split these shortcodes to:

```
array(
    0 => '[shortcode-1 attr1 attr2]
    [child-shortcode-1 attr1="231czx"]
        ...
    [/child-shortcode-1]
    [child-shortcode-2 /]
[/shortcode-1]',
    1 => '[shortcode-2 attr1="cxzc"]
    ...
[/shortcode-2]',
    3 => '[shortcode-3 attr1="123" attr2="456" /]'
);
```

Thank you!

Comment: It appears you have answered your own question.

Comment: No. I want the string to contain shortcodes to be split into an array of shortcodes.

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress already has built in support for [**Nested Shortcodes**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Nested_Shortcodes)provided their handler functions support it by recursively calling.

So if you have for example:

```
[tag-a]
   [tag-b]
      [tag-c]
   [/tag-b]
[/tag-a]
```

As long as you recursively call **`do_shortcode`** in your shortcode function, all the shortcodes would be parsed.

So you would define the functions for your shortcodes as such:

**For tag-a:**

```
function tag_a( $atts ){
    $output = "";
    return do_shortcode($output);
}
add_shortcode( 'tag-a', 'tag_a' );
```

**For tag-b:**

```
function tag_b( $atts ){
    $output = "";
    return do_shortcode($output);
}
add_shortcode( 'tag-b', 'tag_b' );
```

**For tag-c:**

```
function tag_c( $atts ){
    $output = "";
    return do_shortcode($output);
}
add_shortcode( 'tag-c', 'tag_c' );
```